# In Elixir how do you initialize a struct with a map variable

Tags: elixir

I know its possible to create a struct via `%User{ email: 'blah@blah.com' }`. But if I had a variable `params = %{email: 'blah@blah.com'}` is there a way to create that struct using that variable for eg, `%User{ params }`.

This gives an error, just wondering if you can explode it or some other way?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You should use the [`struct/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#struct/2) function. From the docs:

```
defmodule User do
  defstruct name: "john"
end

struct(User)
#=> %User{name: "john"}

opts = [name: "meg"]
user = struct(User, opts)
#=> %User{name: "meg"}

struct(user, unknown: "value")
#=> %User{name: "meg"}
```

Comment: If you have enforced keys and want to make sure they exist in the map use `struct!/2` instead.

Comment: I'm confused. This answer shows initialization of a struct from a keyword list. But the question asks about struct from a map.

Comment: Got it! `struct/2` also works for a map. So, `opts = %{name: "meg"}` works.

Answer (score 27):

The previous answers are both good, with one caveat:  The keys in the struct are atoms, the keys in your hash might be strings.  Using the struct() method will only copy over the keys that match, and strings won't match to the atoms.  Example:

```
defmodule User do
  defstruct name: "john"
end

opts = %{"name" => "meg"}
user = struct(User, opts)
#=> %User{name: "john"}
```

Using merge is odd, too, because it will "undo" the struct nature of the Map:

```
user = Map.merge(%User{}, opts)
#=> %{:__struct__ => User, :name => "john", "name" => "meg"}
```

Found this on the elixir-lang-talk Google Group, from Jose himself:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elixir-lang-talk/6geXOLUeIpI/L9einu4EEAAJ

> That's pretty much the way to go except you can do everything in one pass:
>
> ```
> def to_struct(kind, attrs) do
>   struct = struct(kind)
>   Enum.reduce Map.to_list(struct), struct, fn {k, _}, acc ->
>     case Map.fetch(attrs, Atom.to_string(k)) do
>       {:ok, v} -> %{acc | k => v}
>       :error -> acc
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

Comment: Jose's answer (and yours by deduction) should be the accepted one, for the reason of being from Jose (joking). Using merge caused me problems, and yes, you completely lose the struct nature.

Comment: Thanks for this, I needed a pretty generic way to initialise structs from all kinds of maps and this was the basis of my hack to do this https://github.com/chrisjowen/ExMapper

Answer (score 17):

Another way of doing it using [`Map.merge/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Map.html#merge/2):

> **[merge(map1, map2)](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Map.html#merge/2)**

Example:

```
params
#=> %{email: "blah@blah.com"}

%User{} |> Map.merge(params)
#=> %User{ email: 'blah@blah.com' }
```

Comment: This method cannot be used if you have enforced_keys in your struct.