# How To Enumerate Over A Map To Produce A List of Structs

Tags: elixir

I'm new to Elxir.

If I have the following Map

```
recos = %{"itemScores" => [%{"item" => "i0", "score" => 0.0126078259487225},
%{"item" => "i3", "score" => 0.007569829148848128},
%{"item" => "i4", "score" => 0.007023984270125072},
%{"item" => "i33", "score" => 0.0068045477730524495}]}
```

(This is a map right?)

How would I enumerate over all the itemScores in order to produce of list of RecommendationItems?

```
defmodule RecommendedItem do
  defstruct [:item, :score]
end
```

I'm thinking it's going to invoice Enum.map(recos["itemScores"], fn->) in some way, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Elixir how do you initialize a struct with a map variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927635/in-elixir-how-do-you-initialize-a-struct-with-a-map-variable)

Comment: That doesn't look like a duplicate to me @CoderDennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do what you want:

```
defmodule RecommendedItem do
  defstruct item: "", score: 0
end

defmodule Demo do

  defp parse_list([]), do: []

  defp parse_list([%{"item" => i, "score" => s} | tail]) do
    [%RecommendedItem{item: i, score: s} | parse_list(tail) ]
  end

  def create_recommend_list(%{"itemScores" => score_list})  do
    parse_list(score_list)
  end

end

# And this is how you'd call it.

recos = %{"itemScores" => [%{"item" => "i0", "score" => 0.0126078259487225},
%{"item" => "i3", "score" => 0.007569829148848128},
%{"item" => "i4", "score" => 0.007023984270125072},
%{"item" => "i33", "score" => 0.0068045477730524495}]}

l = Demo.create_recommend_list(recos)

# l = [%RecommendedItem{item: "i0", score: 0.0126078259487225},
# %RecommendedItem{item: "i3", score: 0.007569829148848128},
# %RecommendedItem{item: "i4", score: 0.007023984270125072},
# %RecommendedItem{item: "i33", score: 0.0068045477730524495}]
```

I hope that helps.  While I think I understand what you're asking, I don't think converting each map to a struct is really what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks.  For your comments about not converting it....  you think I should just leave it as a Map?  tell me more

Comment: I'm just not quite sure where converting it to a struct gains you a lot. I don't know your use case so I may be way off base but a struct is just a map with default values and a little more compile time checking.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @zaboco's comment for pointing out that `struct/2` won't work because your map has string keys instead of atom keys.

This is how to do it in a call to `Enum.map`:

```
Enum.map(recos["itemScores"], fn %{"item" => item, "score" => score} -> %RecommendedItem{item: item, score: score} end)
```

I tested and verified the code this time.

Comment: I guess this won't work as it is, since the map uses `string` keys, while the struct has `atom` keys. I think some sort of conversion needs to be done on each item to change the keys to atoms, like `Enum.map p, fn {k, v} -> {String.to_atom(k), v} end`. Or maybe there is a better way.

Comment: @zaboco I missed that detail. Thanks!