# elixir initialise struct with another struct

Tags: struct, elixir

What if I have the following struct:

```
%Registration{email: "john@gmail.com", first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe"}
```

And I want to create two different structs from it:

```
%Account{email: "john@gmail.com", password: nil, ...}
%Profile{first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", age: nil, ...}
```

I have already taken a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927635/in-elixir-how-do-you-initialize-a-struct-with-a-map-variable), but if I do

```
registration = %Registration{email: "john@gmail.com", first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe"}
struct(Account, registration)
```

I receive `protocol Enumerable not implemented for %Registration{...`

So I have to use Map.from_struct

```
registration = %Registration{email: "john@gmail.com", first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe"}
struct(Account, Map.from_struct(registration))
```

But I think it is not very clean. So I was just thinking is there a better way to do this? This should be quite a common problem, right?

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation:

> Converts a struct to map. 
>   It accepts the struct module or a struct itself and simply removes the
>   **struct** field from the struct.

The function exists for a reason. I don't see the way you did it as being a problem really. If it is a common problem I haven't seen it before. If you want to have a more expressive or cleaner code you may try:

```
registration = %Registration{email: "john@gmail.com", first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe"} |> Map.from_struct
struct(Account, registration)
```

or other equivalent code by checking the docs [here](https://devdocs.io/elixir/elixir/kernel#struct/2).

Comment: your code throws an error `protocol Enumerable not implemented for %Registration{...`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily, but in a bit hacky way - just delegate protocol functions to `Enumerable.Map`:

```
  defmodule Contact do
    defstruct [:name, group: "", version: "", status: :latent]

    defimpl Enumerable, for: Contact do
      defdelegate([count(e), member?(e, m), reduce(e, a, f)], 
                  to: Enumerable.Map)
    end
  end
```

or in a bit more proper way like

```
  defmodule Contact do
    defstruct [:name, group: "", version: "", status: :latent]

    defimpl Enumerable do
      alias Enumerable, as: E
      def count(c), do: Map.from_struct(c) |> E.count()
      def member?(c, m), do: Map.from_struct(c) |> E.member?(m)
      def reduce(c, a, f), do: Map.from_struct(c) |> E.reduce(a, f)
    end
  end
```

`Enumerable.count` implementation can be generated with macro to return struct members count which is already known at compile time.
`Enumerable.member?` can also be generated with macro or written by hand or delegated again to `Enumerable.Map.member?` to remove runtime penalty of `Map.from_struct`.

All the code above is generic so it can be placed to `use`-able module like

```
defmodule StructEnumerable do
  defmacro __using__(opts \\ []) do
    quote do
      defimpl Enumerable do
        alias Enumerable, as: E
        def count(c), do: Map.from_struct(c) |> E.count()
        def member?(c, m), do: Map.from_struct(c) |> E.member?(m)
        def reduce(c, a, f), do: Map.from_struct(c) |> E.reduce(a, f)
      end

      # you can also add following code
      # to provide Fetch behaviour implementation
      # for your structs
      defdelegate([
        fetch(t, k),
        get_and_update(t, k, l)
      ], to: Map)
    end
  end
end
```

and embed it like

```
  defmodule Contact do
    defstruct [:name, group: "", version: "", status: :latent]
    use StructEnumerable
  end
```

Comment: Looks like I answered a wrong question - "how to do it" instead of "what is the best way". 
I'm not sure if is it a good way - it involves relatively large runtime penalty, so I would prefer writing macro working like `Kernel.struct` but with field matching done in compile time.

Comment: I actually ended up doing `registration_map = registration |> Map.from_struct |> Map.delete(:__meta__)` and then `struct(Account, registration_map)` Your solution is too advanced for me :)