# validate request input phoenix elixir

Tags: validation, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm struggling to find something in the documentation that seems like it should be there...

In Phoenix I see validation at the point of trying to create an Ecto change set, but I'm not seeing much prior to that, upon validating the actual user input.

I'm not really a fan of exposing my data models across API boundaries, and I would rather just have structs representing the requests and responses, as they are likely very different shapes to my actual data models.

I'd like a way of converting user input to a struct and using some kind of validation framework to determine if the input is valid before I even think about hitting a database.

I've found https://github.com/CargoSense/vex and have gone down the route of converting the input to a struct, and using their validation, but there are a few things that worry me about this approach, namely:

- I hear that there are issues with atoms in Elixir, and as structs are basically atom keyed maps, am I going to run into this atom exhaustion issue converting user input to these?
- I also have some structs that would have nested structs. I'm currently checking the default value provided.  If it's a struct doing some magic, based on the answers here [In Elixir how do you initialize a struct with a map variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927635/in-elixir-how-do-you-initialize-a-struct-with-a-map-variable), to automatically convert a nested map to my nested struct. But again, I'm not sure if this is sensible.
- The validations I'm defining in one DSL will be very similar in my Ecto models, and I would rather be using this for both.

Basically, how would you go about validating user input correctly in a Phoenix app. Am I on the right lines, or way off?

Comment: 1) If you are gonna dynamically convert user's input into atoms, you are gonna DOS yourself eventually since atoms are not garbage collected. 2) As one way to go, you can create forms with whatever names you prefer, validate those with ecto validations (maybe in a separate `form` module, like `RegistrationForm` for example) and then, if everything is correct, rename the fields and put them into a proper changeset and send it to the database.

Comment: (1) shouldn't be a problem unless you're converting arbitrary user input to atoms. Just creating a struct will not cause any problems since they use a fixed set of atoms as keys.

Comment: 1) Cheers Dogbert I thought that was the case and actually looking at the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927635/in-elixir-how-do-you-initialize-a-struct-with-a-map-variable which I'm using as a base Im not crating any more atoms at all, I'm simply converting the struct atom keys to string to retrieve the value form the user input. 

2) Using Ecto I don't want to define a schema for the input, it seems wrong. But actually it seems like I can just use https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/0.2.5/Ecto.Validator.html

Comment: Wow I just realised that link to Ecto docs was way old :)

Comment: For posterity: use https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#input_validations/2 . Here is a good blog post about it: https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/08/11/changeset-form-validation-bindings