# Convert maps to struct

Tags: elixir

I am trying to convert maps to struct as follow:

I have a map:

```
iex(6)> user                      
%{"basic_auth" => "Basic Ym1hOmphYnJhMTc=", "firstname" => "foo",
  "lastname" => "boo"}
```

The value should be applied to struct:

```
iex(7)> a = struct(UserInfo, user)
%SapOdataService.Auth.UserInfo{basic_auth: nil, firstname: nil, lastname: nil}
```

As you can see, the values of struct is nil, why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927635/in-elixir-how-do-you-initialize-a-struct-with-a-map-variable

Comment: @sobolevn that is exactly what the OP tried. As JustMichael suggested, it does not work because the map has string keys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To expand on JustMichael's answer, you can first convert the keys to atoms, using `String.to_existing_atom/1`, then `Kernel.struct/2` to build the struct:

```
user_with_atom_keys = for {key, val} <- user, into: %{} do
  {String.to_existing_atom(key), val}
end

user_struct = struct(UserInfo, user_with_atom_keys)
# %UserInfo{basic_auth: "Basic Ym1hOmphYnJhMTc=", firstname: "foo",
 lastname: "boo"}
```

Note that this uses `String.to_existing_atom/1` to prevent the VM from reaching the global Atom limit.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [exconstructor](https://github.com/appcues/exconstructor). It does exactly what you need.

Here's a small example:

```
defmodule TestStruct do
  defstruct field_one: nil,
            field_two: nil,
            field_three: nil,
            field_four: nil
  use ExConstructor
end

TestStruct.new(%{"field_one" => "a", "fieldTwo" => "b", :field_three => "c", :FieldFour => "d"})
# => %TestStruct{field_one: "a", field_two: "b", field_three: "c", field_four: "d"}
```

Link to the documentation: http://hexdocs.pm/exconstructor/ExConstructor.html

Comment: Unmaintained library, unfortunately.

Comment: Does something like this need to be maintained, it should be relatively bug free and work. Elixir isn't constantly changing like javascript...

Answer (score 3):

I'd use Ecto's changesets for this:

```
defmodule UserInfo do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "user_info" do
    field :basic_auth, :string
    field :firstname, :string
    field :lastname, :string
  end
end
```

then somewhere in your code

```
import Ecto.Changeset

user_struct = cast(%UserInfo{}, 
                   your_user_map, 
                   UserInfo.__schema__(:fields)) 
              |> apply_changes
```

the nice thing about this use of ecto is that you also have added benefits like validation and you do not have to worry fields in your map are strings or atoms.

Answer (score 2):

My wild guess would that it doesn't work because you have keys as strings in the map and as atoms in the struct.

Answer (score 0):

```
  %{"basic_auth" => "Basic Ym1hOmphYnJhMTc=", "firstname" => "foo", "lastname" => "boo"}
  |> Poison.encode
  |> (fn {:ok, json} -> json end).()
  |> Poison.decode(as: %SapOdataService.Auth.UserInfo{})
```

or

```
  ~S({"basic_auth":"Basic Ym1hOmphYnJhMTc=","firstname":"foo","lastname":"boo"})
  |> Poison.decode(as: %SapOdataService.Auth.UserInfo{})
```

note that this will not compile with `@enforce_keys` on `UserInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
%User{username: "test"} = struct(User, %{username: "test", password: "secret"})
```

from https://elixir-examples.github.io/examples/map-to-struct