# Elixir - convert http response json to ecto.schema object

Tags: json, elixir, ecto, elixir-poison, httpoison

I am a newbie to elixir. I have a Ecto Schema

```
  defmodule MyScoreSchema do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "historical_extra_fuels" do
    field :average, :float
    field :count, :float
    field :percent, :float
    field :name, :string
  end


  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:average, :count, :percent])
    |> validate_required([])
  end
end
```

and parent schema

```
defmodule OverallScore do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "OverallScore" do
    field :avg_pass, :float
    field :avg_fail, :float
    field :total_students, :float
    embeds_many :my_score_schema, MyScoreSchema
  end
  @required_fields ~w[]a
  @optional_fields ~w[avg_pass, avg_fail, total_students ]a


  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, @optional_fields, required: false )
    |> cast_embed(:my_score_schema, required: false)
  end
end
```

And have a HTTP REST API `http://localhost:8080/getScoreData` which gives data

```
{
      "avgPass": 85.55,
      "avgFail": 14.45,
      "totalStudents": 80.0,
      "myScoreSchema": [
        {
          "average": 80.0,
          "count": 8.0,
          "percent": 80.0,
          "name": "John"
        },
        {
          "average": 90.0,
          "count": 8.0,
          "percent": 90.0,
          "name": "Cena"
        },
        {
          "average": 80.0,
          "count": 8.0,
          "percent": 80.0,
          "name": "Sunny"
        },
        {
          "average": 70.0,
          "count": 8.0,
          "percent": 70.0,
          "name": "Michael"
        }
      ]
    }
```

and the code

```
  url = "http://localhost:8080/getScoreData"
   Logger.info("the url is #{url}")
   case HTTPoison.get(url) do
     {:ok, %{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
       overall_score = Jason.decode!(body, as: [%OverallScore{}])
       {:ok, overall_score}
   end
```

This somehow works and don't give error but the result is some `struct` and not really `OverallScore` `ecto` `schema object`

Comment: What is the result? You receive a single `%OverallScore{}`, why do you try to encode to the list?

Comment: Where have you found that `Jason.decode!/1` accepts `as:` option?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest instead of using that "as: [%OverallScore{}]" syntax, you use the changeset in your model that you already have. This would look something like this:

```
  url = "http://localhost:8080/getScoreData"
   Logger.info("the url is #{url}")
   case HTTPoison.get(url) do
     {:ok, %{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
       response = Jason.decode!(body)
       overall_score = OverallScore.changeset(%OverallScore{}, response)
       {:ok, overall_score}
   end
```

Changesets are generally the best way to get objects into ecto structs as they will run through your changeset validation properly. This has the added benefit of it dropping anything in the "response" field that it isn't in the changeset's cast call without any errors. You'll also be able to quickly check if it's valid, and if so you can insert it into the database with your ecto repo.

Comment: The `overall_score` here is coming as `#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %` and not the OverallScore object. I strictly want to return OverallScore object and not Changeset. I think this will remain a changeset object unless I do `Repo.insert` which I don't need.

Comment: @veer7 if you just want to build the struct rather than acting with a changeset then you will want to use the "Kernel.struct/2" function as shown here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41980865/2265722. As outlined in the answer linked you'll want to convert the map from string keys to atom keys first.